# Connectors that protect wires from breaking when it is resonating alot

Tags: pcb, connector, resonance

I am building a robot vehicle, that is resonating alot when it is in rough areas. Cause of this the wires in the robot will resonate a bit too. When this happens every now and then a 'vein' (tiny copper wire in the wire) of the wire will break off. After a certain time the wire will break off from the connector.

Are there connectors that will prevent this? Or is there another solution to prevent this? I am currently using normal [screw terminal blocks](http://nl.farnell.com/te-connectivity-buchanan/282834-2/terminal-block-pcb-2way-30-16awg/dp/2112482) from TE connectivity. The connector should be able to handle atleast 5A.

Comment: Have you tried using zip ties to hold the wires against a stable structure?

Comment: I already came up with the same idea but there ain't a stable structure. the distance also ain't that big, just a few centimeter.

Comment: Not even the PCB? Drill holes if you need to.

Comment: it should be possible to drill holes in the PCB, will try it out.

Comment: Get an old telephone hand set or coiled extension cord. They use "tinsel wire" which is fine stranded wire wound spiral around latex cores. It can stretch and shake practically forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should stop everything flapping about.  In high vibration environments (aerospace, etc), you'd find everything tied or laced in some way to stop it shaking.  You might even find that the lacing has then had epoxy or some other sticky goop put on it to stiffen it further.

Making everything stiffer will also raise the resonant frequency of the whole system, which may be helpful too.

Here's a picture of the ultimate in robot vehicles for hostile environments (Curiosity) - note the lacing on the cables...

[image]